# How to change Firebase account from android project

Tags: java, android, firebase, github

I have created an android project with firebase and i pushed it into github.
When i cloned it , then the project automatically connected to that firebase accoount .

My Question is how to change that project's firebase account / or diffrent firebase project ?

Comment: there should be a configuration file. Are you using firebase Java SDK?

Comment: for which purpose do you use firebase?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It sounds like you've included the `google-services.json` file into your repo on Github. That indeed means that if someone clones that repo, their copy of the app will be accessing your project.

If you don't want this to happen, exclude the `google-services.json` file from the repo, and tell developers to create their own Firebase project, and put **their** `google-services.json` into the app directory. The Firebase console instructs them to do that when they add an Android app to that project.